# i was making rdp on github i am having a error Error: Process completed with exit code 1

Tags: github

```
  env:
    NGROK_AUTH_TOKEN: 
NAME:
   authtoken - save authtoken to configuration file

USAGE:
   ngrok authtoken [command options] [arguments...]

DESCRIPTION:
   The authtoken command modifies your configuration file to include
   the specified authtoken. By default, this configuration file is located
   at $HOME/.ngrok2/ngrok.yml

   The ngrok.com service requires that you sign up for an account to use
   many advanced service features. In order to associate your client with
   an account, it must pass a secret token to the ngrok.com service when it
   starts up. Instead of passing this authtoken on every invocation, you may
   use this command to save it into your configuration file so that your
   client always authenticates you properly.

EXAMPLE:
    ngrok authtoken BDZIXnhJt2HNWLXyQ5PM_qCaBq0W2sNFcCa0rfTZd

OPTIONS:
   --config         save in this config file, default: ~/.ngrok2/ngrok.yml
   --log "false"    path to log file, 'stdout', 'stderr' or 'false'
   --log-format "term"  log record format: 'term', 'logfmt', 'json'
   --log-level "info"   logging level

ERROR:  You must pass a single argument, the authtoken to save to configuration file.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests try passing the auth token as a string

i.e.

$ ngrok authtoken "BDZIXnhJt2HNWLXyQ5PM_qCaBq0W2sNFcCa0rfTZd"